# Specializing constructors with requires for a possibly reference type

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, c++20, c++-concepts

I need to make a wrapper class template that can possibly contain a reference member. I have both copy and move constructors defined, where references of the wrapped type are passed as arguments. This is all good if the type is not a reference. But if it is, both `type&` and `type&&` become lvalue references, and the two constructors conflict with each other.

I tried defining one set of constructors for the case where the type is not a reference and another for when it is, making use of the `requires` clause, as shown in the code below. But this doesn't compile if the type is a reference! GCC somehow treats the poisoned constructors as still valid.

Am I misunderstanding how `requires` works, or is this a bug? Here is the same example in the compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/qjMxx3nGE

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct S {
  using type = T;
  type x;
  S(const type& x) requires(!std::is_reference_v<type>)
  : x(x) { }
  S(type&& x) requires(!std::is_reference_v<type>)
  : x(x) { }
  S(type x) requires(std::is_reference_v<type>)
  : x(x) { }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int i = 5;
  S<int&> s(i);
  return s.x;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every function you define has to be distinct in some way - different name, different parameters, different constraints, etc.

For `T=int&`, your three constructors are:

```cpp
S(int&) requires (!std::is_reference_v<int&>);
S(int&) requires (!std::is_reference_v<int&>);
S(int&) requires (std::is_reference_v<int&>);
```

The first two are the same, but there are two of them. That's an error. You need to differentiate these cases.

`requires` doesn't prevent the function from existing in the way that you might think - it just removes it as a candidate from overload resolution. It doesn't behave like a hypothetical `if` would:

```cpp
if (std::is_reference_v<T>) {
    S(T x);
} else {
    S(T const&);
    S(T&&);
}
```

---

It'd be easier to simply add a single constructor template that's constrained on being constructible:

```cpp
template <typename U> requires std::constructible_from<T, U>
S(U&& u) : x(std::forward<U>(u)) { }
```

Or provide a specialization for `S<T&>` and split the constructors that way.

Comment: Oh, I see. So the problem is that the compiler can't tell if all these functions may need to be instantiated, in which case, they would all end up with the same name.

Comment: @SU3 Well, all the constructors have the same "name", they're just `S`. But in this case, the issue is that they [correspond](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#def:correspond) while not actually being the same.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I used the term "name" loosely. I meant that the compiled symbols for the functions representing these constructors would have to end up with the same name.